# In flask, paragraph is overwriting again but I want to print them separately

Tags: python, html, css, flask, jinja2

Snippet of HTML:

```
<div class="split left" >
<div class="centered">
<div class="container">

     <p>Hi!</p>

  </div>


   <div class="darker">


        <p>{{message}}</p>
    </div>

    <form action="{{ url_for('index')}}" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="client" placeholder="Enter Message" class="text" id="message">
     <button class="glow-on-hover">Send</button>

        </form>
```

Snippet of FLASK code:

```
@app.route("/")
def start():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def index():
    message = request.form.get("client")
    return render_template("index.html", message=message)
```

Whenever I enter value and press send button it overwrites

but I want to print a new paragraph each time I press send button. The list can not be useful in my opinion because it is something like a chat app. So the list will only display one recipient's message. Any effective and easy way???

Answer (score 0):

here I have recreated your code and it seems working fine. Usually, the form refreshes the current page which leads to overwriting of contents.

Python Code:

```
@app.route("/")
def start():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/message")
def index():
    message = request.args.get("msg")
    return message
```

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function textGen(){
            $.get('/message', {"msg": document.getElementById('message').value }).done(function(data){
            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += `<p>${data}</p>`;
            })
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="split left">
        <div class="centered">
            <div class="container">

                <p>Hi!</p>

            </div>


            <div class="darker" id="text">

            </div>

                <input type="text" name="client" placeholder="Enter Message" class="text" id="message">
                <button class="glow-on-hover" onclick="textGen()">Send</button>


</body>

</html>
```

In both the components, I have created msg handler in flask and msg sender in javascript using jquery. So this solution will work in your scenario. Take a look and please write to me if you face any errors or difficulties in making this code work. And I'm not using the form so it will prevent overwriting.